# Software Testing Standards for web applications

Tags: testing, standards

Can someone define the software testing standards for web application? We have our own set of standards on which we done testing. Its very simple like text font size, error message display locations, alignment of text boxes, proper validation etc. I am very much interested in knowing the ISO standards for software testing with some examples of those standards being implemented. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the ISO standard for Software Testing is being redeveloped under the reference [ISO/IEC 29119](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_29119). This is work in progress and can be read on the [official web site](http://www.softwaretestingstandard.org/). But not that there is a [strong resistance to this standard by a portion of the testing community](http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/stop29119).

Personally, I am rather inclined to not find much value in this standard. The quality expectations and mission as a QA is so much context driven, that a standard does not help so much. But well, it is one source of information I guess.

Answer (score 0):

SO/IEC/IEEE 29119 Software Testing is an internationally agreed set of standards for software testing that can be used within any software development life cycle or organization. By implementing these standards, you will be adopting the only internationally-recognized and agreed standards for software testing, which will provide your organization with a high-quality approach to testing that can be communicated throughout the world.
Following is the URL for detailed information:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing/software_testing_iso_standards.htm

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Standards can be Check Using w3c - HTML Validator , w3c Css Validator , W3c - Link Checker & w3c Usability Checker